# Ignore all but newest item in source collection with Observable.SelectMany

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Given

```
// observable getting files in folder as they are created
IObservable<string> files = GetFilesAsTheyAreCreated();
```

and function

```
// gets lines of the file as they are written
IObservable<string> GetLines(string filePath)
```

I would like to create observable that returns lines written to the last created file. As newer files are created, I would like to start getting lines from that files instead. Right now I have following code:

```
var lines = files.SelectMany(f => GetLines(f));
```

The issue with this is that I get all the lines added to older files too. Is there a way to ignore those old lines?

**Note:** I'm mostly interested in cancelling `GetLines` observable as it is running on new thread.

Can this be achieved with built in operators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is super simple:

```
var lines = files.Select(f => GetLines(f)).Switch();
```

The `.Switch()` operator turns an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` into a `IObservable<T>` by only returning inner values from the most recent outer observable. Exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I've felt that such common use case should be supported out of the box but I couldn't find it with intellisense in VS. I'll rtm next time :)